# Orchard blog with Live Writer

Tags: orchardcms, windows-live-writer

I'm using Orchard 1.8 and I want to manage a blog with Windows Live Writer 2012.

Is there any simple solution to add a field image to the blog post content type and let the user fill it in Writer?

My idea is show a widget like [image - title - some text] so any advice is welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Live Writer only allows for simple blog post editing. It does not do structured data beyond what's provided by standard blogging APIs. It is trivial however to add images inside of a blog post's body.